# How to write a function for checking a string for unconventional characters in grepl?

Tags: r, grepl

I've created a simple grepl function for checking if the character string is longer or equal to 8 characters and doesn't include spaces. It seems that for my purposes it is too liberate thought. How can I make a grepl function check if there are only letters and numbers, not any other symbols included in the string?

The function below returns FALSE when the string isn't at least 8 characters long and if it includes any spaces.

```
check_the_string <- function(x){
  if(nchar(x) >= 8){
    
    if(grepl("(\\s+)", x) == TRUE) {
       FALSE
       } else {
       TRUE
       }
    
  } else {FALSE}
}
```

I am pretty bad at understanding how the conditions in grepl works. I've tried putting into grepl condition `grepl("[:punct:]", x)` and `grepl("^[:punct:]+$", x)` to check for any symbols and `[:alnum:]` in place of `[:punct:]` to check if there are only letters, but these seems to always return FALSE.

I will be pleased with a specific solution or only a push in the right direction to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for ensuring an entire string is alphanumeric is `"^[[:alnum:]]+$"`. The `^` means "match the start of the string", then `[[:alnum:]]+` means "match an arbitrary number of alphanumeric characters", then `$` means "match the end of the string". So if there is anything other than alphanumeric characters between the beginning and end of the string, you won't get a match.

You can also simplify your logic a bit. Writing `if(grepl("blah", x) == TRUE) FALSE else TRUE` is just a long way of writing `!grepl("blah", x)`. Also, instead of a branching `if` statement, you can use the `&` operator to test for whether both logical tests are `TRUE`

So your function becomes a one-liner:

```r
check_the_string <- function(x)  nchar(x) >= 8 & grepl("^[[:alnum:]]+$", x)
```

And we can test it out on a few strings:

```r
# More than 8 characters but contains a space
check_the_string("hello world")
#> [1] FALSE

# More than 8 characters but contains punctuation
check_the_string("helloworld!")
#> [1] FALSE

# Less than 8 characters
check_the_string("hello")
#> [1] FALSE

# More than 8 characters - letters only
check_the_string("HelloWorld")
#> [1] TRUE

# More than 8 characters - letters and numbers
check_the_string("HelloWorld2020")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: actually `[[:alnum:]]{8,}` will be better.